# read in SQLite to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

Is there a way to read in a SQLite DB without doing a linked server?

I would typically use R to read in these dataset but I'd like to query them within SQL Server Management Studio in a similar fashion without linking a server.

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(),"db.path")
df <- RSQLite::dbReadTable(con, name="tbl_name")
RSQLite::dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: SQL Server by itself does not support SQLite. It only does so using linked servers and ADO drivers.

Comment: SSMS connects to SQL Server instances only and is not designed to directly access any other dbms. Short answer - no.